# Como bloquear a movimentação do cursor no masked input?

Tags: jquery, html, masked-input-plugin

Estou utilizando o plugin [jQuery Masked Input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

```
<input name="dueDate" class="form-control input-mask-date" type="text" placeholder="Data de Vencimento" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" required="">
```

E faço a ativação do *masked input* através da *classe* em JavaScript.

```
$(".input-mask-date").mask("99/99/9999");
```

Entretanto, eu consigo ao clicar no canto, **ficar** com o cursor no último caractere da máscara.

Como eu posso bloquear isso? Ou como voltar o cursor sempre para o primeiro caractere quando clicar?

[image: Print do Masked Input]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução utilizando **jQuery** bem interessante no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area) que *não é uma propriedade do masked input plugin*, mas resolve seu problema:

```
$.fn.selectRange = function(start, end) {
    if(end === undefined) {
        end = start;
    }
    return this.each(function() {
        if('selectionStart' in this) {
            this.selectionStart = start;
            this.selectionEnd = end;
        } else if(this.setSelectionRange) {
            this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        } else if(this.createTextRange) {
            var range = this.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', end);
            range.moveStart('character', start);
            range.select();
        }
    });
};
```

Você pode utilizar da seguinte maneira:

```
$(".input-mask-date").click(function() {
  $(".input-mask-date").selectRange(0);
});
```

Sempre que o evento de `click` for acionado, o cursor é posicionado no início do `input`.

Criei um [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wsr8z/1373/) com um exemplo.

Comment: Até o momento foi que resolveu melhor o problema.